# How to pass the seleted one radiobutton to jquery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, radio-button, html.radiobuttonlist

i have two @html.radiobutton in mvc3 . I need to pass the selected one value to jquery

my code:

```
 @Html.RadioButton("gender", "1", false, new { id = "id1" }) male

   @Html.RadioButton("gender", "2", true, new { id = "id2" }) female
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [overload of RadioButton method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492690.aspx).

```
Gender:
@Html.RadioButton("Gender", "1", true, new { id = "yourId" }) Male
@Html.RadioButton("Gender", "2", false, new { id = "yourId" }) Female
```

Hope it helps.

---

**Edit**

`$('input[name=Gender]:radio:checked')` will get you the selected radio button, while `$('input[name=Gender]:radio:not(:checked)'` will get you the unselected radio button.

```
$(function(){
     $('input[name=Gender]:radio').click(function () {
          //Here we can get the selected radio button
          var selected=$('input[name=Gender]:radio:checked');
          alert('You have selected'+ selected);
     });
});
```

Comment: How to pass the seleted one radiobutton to jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Set group name for radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk">
```

Radio buttons are slightly different from other HTML form elements in that they present multiple options and only allow one choice. This being the case, the HTML Editor contains a special tool for keeping your radio button options organized. Here's how to use it:

**[ADDING A RADIO BUTTON GROUP TO AN HTML FORM](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/adding-a-radio-button-group-to-an-html-form/)**

Comment: i need to this type  @Html.RadioButton("rdoId", "Id", false, new { @onchange = "Change(this, true, true, null)" })&nbsp;value

Answer (score 0):

Check this link http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio

Simple ... :)

here both radio lines has name="sex"  ,that indicates same radio group to the HTML so you can select one among Two.